# Healthchecks UI not showing, resulting in a blankpage [.NET 6]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

**What happened**:  The default Healthchecks UI page displays a blank page.

**What you expected to happen**: To properly see the default Healthchecks UI page.

**How to reproduce it (as minimally and precisely as possible)**:  In Program.cs, use app.MapHealthChecks() and app.MapHealthChecksUI()

**Source code sample**: Below is the *Program.cs* file.

```
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using MonitoringApi.HealthChecks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddCheck<RandomHealthCheck>("Site Health Check")
    .AddCheck<RandomHealthCheck>("Database Health Check");

builder.Services.AddHealthChecksUI(opts =>
{
    opts.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("api", "/health");
    opts.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5);
    opts.SetMinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications(10);
}).AddInMemoryStorage();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();
app.MapHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});
app.MapHealthChecksUI();

app.Run();
```

**Anything else we need to know?**: Possibly occuring if you have installed Watchdogs before.

**Environment**:

- .NET Core version 6
- Healthchecks version 6.0.5
- Operative system: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was by replacing in **Program.cs**, the app.MapHealtchChecks() and app.MapHealthChecksUI() with app.UseHealthChecks() and app.UseHealthChecksUI() as seen below.

```
using HealthChecks.UI.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.HealthChecks;
using MonitoringApi.HealthChecks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
        .AddCheck<RandomHealthCheck>("Site Health Check")
        .AddCheck<RandomHealthCheck>("Database Health Check");

builder.Services.AddHealthChecksUI(opts =>
{
    opts.AddHealthCheckEndpoint("api","/health");
    opts.SetEvaluationTimeInSeconds(5);
    opts.SetMinimumSecondsBetweenFailureNotifications(10);
}).AddInMemoryStorage();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.UseHealthChecks("/health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    // json response
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
});

app.UseHealthChecksUI(setup =>
{
    setup.UIPath = "/healthchecks-ui"; // ui path
    setup.ApiPath = "/health-ui-api"; // this is the internal ui api
});

app.Run();
```